# How do I create copies of CurrentDb using VBA

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

I need to create copies of the CurrentDB using VBA (approx. 12 copies). The copies need to be clones of the master database containing all the same forms, queries, etc. except only a limited dataset.

`DoCmd.CopyDatabaseFile` seems to be made for this, but only works if you are using it to copy the DB to an MS SQL Server. As MS states on their website:

> Copies the database connected to the current project to a Microsoft
>   SQL Server database file for export.

`docmd.TransferDatabase` only exports the data itself, but not the structure, forms, etc.

Code I have found on the web and adapted doesn't work and throws an error on the `.CopyFile` line saying:

> Run-time error 52: Bad file name or number

This is the code

```
Sub CopyDB()
Dim external_db As Object
Dim sDBsource As String
Dim sDBdest As String

sDBsource = "\\group\bsc\groups\L\BDTP\Compliance\ComplianceData\Compliance Group Reporting.accdb"
sDBdest = "\\group\bsc\groups\L\BDTP\Compliance\ComplianceData\Compliance Group Reporting_2.accdb"""

Set external_db = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
external_db.CopyFile sDBsource, sDBdest, True
Set external_db = Nothing

End Sub
```

How can I fix the above line? Alternatively is there a direct command in Access to create a copy? The "create backup" function would be tailor made for this, but I can not find it in VBA.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like you have an extra quote in sDBdest `accdb"""`
And for database copy you can also use

```
FileCopy sDBsource, sDBdest
```

Instead of Scripting object

Comment: will accept as answer as soon as the system lets me.